Device encryption no longer available after SSD migration
I have a Galaxy Book2 Pro with Windows 11 Home that I've exchanged SSD for and now I can't re-enable device encryption.
The steps I did for the SSD change:

Turned of device encryption for old SSD
Used DiskGenius to clone the contents
Opened up the laptop and switched the SSD to the new one

Now it's like windows does not acknowledge that there is a setting to enable data encryption. When searching for "Data encryption" in windows I get the search result but when going to it I land on the Windows security landing page without any encryption options.
I've tried to clear the TPM both through tpm.msc and bios but no difference. The status for the TPM module is "Ready for use". Available options contain "Please restart the computer to take ownership of TPM" but regardless of how many times I restart that option does not disappear.
Edit: I now recall that when using DiskGenius OS migration feature I thought that I have deselected "Set target disk to boot system via USB" but when reading the summary it had enabled that. Is that something that will make windows refuse to encrypt it?

Are you using Home or Pro license of Windows? What does msinfo32 show about your firmware (in particular, "BIOS mode")?

@u1686_grawity Home version, bios is UEFI.

If you open msinfo32 elevated, it should tell you (2nd line from the bottom) why device encryption is not supported at the moment. If you find no solution, I will offer a trick to use the real Bitlocker even on the home version of Windows. That will work in any case.
